# Is there a way to use a script to set theme colors (ACCENT1, ACCENT2 etc) in Google Slides?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-slides-api, google-slides

I have a Light and a Dark theme and all the Colors are set in a Master theme. Currently, if I want to change the theme, I have to manually import the other theme for it to work. I wanted to create an add-on that will allow me to do this with a click of a button (much like in Powerpoint)

I'm more familiar with using Scripts on Google Sheets so I don't know if it's possible to set ACCENT colors in Google Slides. I know how to change fonts, colors of textbox etc but not this.

Is there a way?

Thank you

[image: In the image, I basically want everything marked as "1" to be the same color - and change when I change that color.]

Answer (score 1):

```
function test(){
  setThemeColors('#000000,
  #ffffff,#424242,#f2f2f2,#41c4dc,
  #34d058,#f5f442,#f55e3b,#9c51b6,
  #c9c9c9,#646464,#a3a3a3')
}


function setThemeColors(hexcolors) {
  // Convert a hex color string to an array of red, green, and blue values.
  function hex2concrete(hexColor) {
    var red = parseInt(hexColor.slice(1, 3), 16) / 255;
    var green = parseInt(hexColor.slice(3, 5), 16) / 255;
    var blue = parseInt(hexColor.slice(5, 7), 16) / 255;
    return [red, green, blue];
  }

  // Split the hexcolors string into an array of hex color strings.
  var hexColors = hexcolors.split(',');

  // Define the COLOR_SCHEME object.
  var COLOR_SCHEME = {
    colors: []
  };

  // Define the theme color types in the correct order.
  var colorTypes = 'DARK1,LIGHT1,DARK2,LIGHT2,ACCENT1,ACCENT2,ACCENT3,ACCENT4,ACCENT5,ACCENT6,HYPERLINK,FOLLOWED_HYPERLINK'.split(',');

  // Loop over the hex colors and theme color types.
  for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    // Skip the iteration if the hex color string is empty.
    if (hexColors[i] === '') continue;

    // Convert the hex color to an array of red, green, and blue values.
    var color = hex2concrete(hexColors[i]);

    // Add a color object to the COLOR_SCHEME object.
    COLOR_SCHEME.colors.push({
      type: colorTypes[i],
      color: {
        red: color[0],
        green: color[1],
        blue: color[2]
      }
    });
  }

  // Define the requests to update the page properties.
  var requests = [{
    updatePageProperties: {
      objectId: SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getMasters()[0].getObjectId(),
      pageProperties: {
        colorScheme: COLOR_SCHEME
      },
      fields: 'colorScheme.colors'
    }
  }];

  // Execute the requests.
  Slides.Presentations.batchUpdate({
    requests: requests
  }, SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getId())
}
```

Or, maybe Simpler

```
  function setThemeColors(hexcolors, masterno){
        /* Test setThemeColors(["#000000","#ffffff","#424242","#f2f2f2",
                      "#41c4dc","#34d058","#f5f442","#f55e3b",
                      "#9c51b6","#c9c9c9","#646464","#a3a3a3"], 
                      1) */
        var clrSc = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation()
            .getMasters()[masterno-1].getColorScheme();
        clrSc.setConcreteColor(SlidesApp.ThemeColorType.DARK1,hexcolors[0]).
        setConcreteColor(SlidesApp.ThemeColorType.LIGHT1,hexcolors[1]).
        setConcreteColor(SlidesApp.ThemeColorType.DARK2,hexcolors[2]).
        setConcreteColor(SlidesApp.ThemeColorType.LIGHT2,hexcolors[3]).
        setConcreteColor(SlidesApp.ThemeColorType.ACCENT1,hexcolors[4]).
        setConcreteColor(SlidesApp.ThemeColorType.ACCENT2,hexcolors[5]).
        setConcreteColor(SlidesApp.ThemeColorType.ACCENT3,hexcolors[6]).
        setConcreteColor(SlidesApp.ThemeColorType.ACCENT4,hexcolors[7]).
        setConcreteColor(SlidesApp.ThemeColorType.ACCENT5,hexcolors[8]).
        setConcreteColor(SlidesApp.ThemeColorType.ACCENT6,hexcolors[9]).
        setConcreteColor(SlidesApp.ThemeColorType.HYPERLINK,hexcolors[10]).
        setConcreteColor(SlidesApp.ThemeColorType.FOLLOWED_HYPERLINK,hexcolors[11])
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

### The Slides API features the property [ThemeColorType](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations.pages/other#themecolortype)

To implement a color scheme, you can perform a call to [presentations.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations/batchUpdate) with a [UpdatePagePropertiesRequest](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations/request#updatepagepropertiesrequest).

This lets you define / modify the theme color programamtically and features the following enums (including accents!):

> DARK1 Represents the first dark color.

> LIGHT1    Represents the first light color.

> DARK2 Represents the second dark color.

> LIGHT2 Represents the second light color.

> ACCENT1    Represents the first accent color.

> ACCENT2    Represents the second accent color.

> ACCENT3    Represents the third accent color.

> ACCENT4    Represents the fourth accent color.

> ACCENT5    Represents the fifth accent color.

> ACCENT6    Represents the sixth accent color.

> HYPERLINK  Represents the color to use for hyperlinks.

> FOLLOWED_HYPERLINK Represents the color to use for visited hyperlinks.

> TEXT1  Represents the first text color.

> BACKGROUND1    Represents the first background color.

> TEXT2  Represents the second text color.
> BACKGROUND2

See also the resource [Color Scheme](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations.pages#colorscheme) to udnerstand the ensting of the JSON object.